# PHP ERROR HANDLING : Error message is not Showing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new with PDO and i tried connecting to the database using TRY and CATCH error handling. But the problem is when i intentionally put some errors in my script, the error message is not showing.

connectionDAO.php :

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class connectionDAO {

    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $host = "localhost";
    $database = "RMSs";
    $dbh = null;

    public function openConnection() {
        $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=". $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->database, $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->dbh = setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public function closeConnection() {
        try {
            $this->dbh = null;
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

In the above code, my database name is "RMS" but i intentionally input it wrong. When i go to it's URL(localhost/website/php/connectionDAO.php) it's not showing any errors. what seems to be the problem here?
My main goal for this is to test either the database if connecting properly before proceeding. Can somebody also give me some other example except mine how to test for database connection in PDO?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The way you are trying to report errors is wrong, both by intention and implementation. The proper solution is in the linked answer.

Comment: In short, just get rid of try...catch stuff

Comment: @Fabulous the error should show since my database name is not right(intentionally did it for testing) but the problem is no error is show. .

Comment: @YourCommonSense where is the answer link sir ?

Comment: On top of your of your question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense i edit my question tried what you said but im not sure if im doing right?

Comment: Get rid of that try and catch operators. remove them completely from your code. And you will have your error "handling" first class